# How to convert object to Tuple?

Tags: f#, f#-3.0

I have a variable called value that is an object, Now I know that the value contains a tuple of two types (I dont know what types).

Note : I know the value is a tuple only at runtime.

how can I convert value {object} to value {tuple ('A,'B)} ?

This how I tried to do it

```
type TdlType=
    |TdlBoolean=0
    |TdlInteger=1
    |TdlTag=2
    |Tdldouble=3
    |TdlString=4
    |TdlDecimal=5
    |TdlChar=6
    |TdlTuple=7
and Tdl(_value,_name:string,_valueType:TdlType)=
    let value:obj=_value
    let name:string=_name
    let valueType:TdlType= _valueType
    member this.valueAsTuple: Option<'A*'B>=if valueType<>TdlType.TdlTuple then 
                                               None 
                                            else 
                                               match value with
                                               |(x,y)->Some((x,y)) //The Error is Here
                                               |_->None
```

but I have a error with this code : This expression was expcted to have type obj but here has type 'A*'B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want it to do?

```
open System

type TdlType =
| TdlBoolean = 0
| TdlInteger = 1
| TdlTag = 2
| Tdldouble = 3
| TdlString = 4
| TdlDecimal = 5
| TdlChar = 6
| TdlTuple = 7
and Tdl(value : obj, name : string, valueType : TdlType) =
    member this.GetValueAsTuple<'a, 'b> () =
        if valueType <> TdlType.TdlTuple then 
            None 
        else 
            match value with
            | :? Tuple<'a, 'b> as t -> Some (t.Item1, t.Item2)
            | _ -> None
```

Sample FSI output:

```
> let x = Tdl("Foo", "Foo", TdlType.TdlString);;

val x : Tdl

> x.GetValueAsTuple<string, string>();;
val it : (string * string) option = None
> let y = Tdl(("Foo", 42), "Foo", TdlType.TdlTuple);;

val y : Tdl

> y.GetValueAsTuple<string, int>();;
val it : (string * int) option = Some ("Foo", 42)
```

As a general note, unless you're interacting with some weakly typed outside system, and this is your attempt to getting data from that system into your F# code base, this isn't particularly idiomatic F# code.

What are you really trying to do? What's the motivation for this?

Comment: I have a file syntax called Tdl it is like Xml, but the difference between xml and tdl is in xml all the values is in strings, I mean that when you are trying to read a value from xml it we always be string and you as the user can cast it to what you need,Tdl will return you the value as the object you save it, I mean the if you save a int in a tdl file, and then try to get the value of it the value will return as int. It is very easy to work with files and data when you can save it as an object and then get it in the same object.

Comment: OK, you *are* interacting with an untyped data source :) FWIW, if it's string-based, you may consider taking a look at [FParsec](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec) for a more standardized way of parsing strings. Additionally, F# has a feature called [Type Providers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156509.aspx), which is also intended to make reading data easier. However, unless one already exists for your format, it's probably overkill.